# Part time courses in Jazz music in Germany

Tags: jazz, education

I am a guitar player but had no formal music education and I want to learn Jazz improvisation with guitar as my main instrument.

I am looking for some courses in Jazz guitar in the German music schools (Musikhochschule), but I cannot find anything that offers a degree/diploma for part time studies.

Can anyone suggest any courses that I can take either online or in any music school/college in Germany?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar at all with music education in Germany, but I do have some ideas for what you can do. Mainly, if you want to receive a formal education in jazz, you should look for a private teacher. The best way to do this would be to honestly just ask around. You could even make a flier asking for a private teacher and post the flier all over.

Or, if you just want to get some sort of jazz education and you don't require a private teacher, the internet always has what you are looking for.

- [learnjazzstandards.com](https://www.learnjazzstandards.com/) is a wonderful blog. They post many articles and podcasts weekly and have a variety of experienced jazz musicians on their staff. You're bound to learn a lot here.
- [coursera.com](https://www.coursera.org/learn/jazz-improvisation) is a website with general online courses, but I've linked a specific one about learning jazz improvisation (taught by Gary Burton). There may be other courses as well.
- Some music colleges, such as Berklee (which is an American college) have online courses as well. You can check out this and other colleges about online programs they may have.

Personally, I found a private teacher to be wonderful because it gives you someone you can talk to all the time with all of your questions. However, I've always studied music with a private teacher, so seeing that you were never formally taught guitar, you may do just fine using the internet.

But honestly, the internet has so many resources on jazz improvisation that you can at your own pace. Or, you may even be able to find some helpful books at your local book store.